# hover on siblings only affect siblings upwards

Tags: css, hover

Codepen: https://codepen.io/andrelange91/pen/VyjYBg

I have made the following, example of a sound level which should fill out the other bars on hover. But it is backwards currently... 
And i haven't been able to figure out a way (though i bet it is simple), to reverse that effect.

If i hover on number three it should make the effect on that, and number 2 and 1. 
not 5, 4 and 3.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="volume" tabindex="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuetext="20 percent" data-volume-level-wrapper="">
                                <button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="20" aria-label="lyd 20%"></button>
                                <button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="40" aria-label="lyd 40%"></button>
                                <button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="60" aria-label="lyd 60%"></button>
                                <button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="80" aria-label="lyd 80%"></button>
                                <button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="100" aria-label="lyd 100%"></button>
                            </div>
```

And css:

```
body{
  background:black;
}
.volume {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 65px;
    margin-left: 650px;
    background:white;
    width:200px;
}
.volumeLevel {
    width: 4px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.volume[aria-valuenow="20"] .volumeLevel:first-child {

    background-color: #00A08C;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="20"] {
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="40"] {
    height: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="60"] {
    height: 35px;
    left: 40px;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="80"] {
    height: 40px;
    left: 60px;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="100"] {
    height: 45px;
    left: 80px;
}
.volume .volumeLevel:hover {
    background-color: #00A08C;
}

.volume{
  .volumeLevel:hover ~ .volumeLevel{
        background-color: #00A08C;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the first bar have static colour? If not, a simple reversal feels enough like this:

```html
<div class="volume" tabindex="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="20 percent" data-volume-level-wrapper="">
<button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="100" aria-label="lyd 20%"></button>
<button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="80" aria-label="lyd 40%"></button>
<button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="60" aria-label="lyd 60%"></button>
<button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="40" aria-label="lyd 80%"></button>
<button class="volumeLevel" data-volume-level="20" aria-label="lyd 100%"></button>
</div>
```

If the first bar should have a static colour at the start, a slight change to the css like this might be fine:

```
.volume[aria-valuenow="100"] .volumeLevel:last-child { 
background-color: #00A08C;
}
```

Check this in codepen and see the result...

**Additional edit:**

If you do not want to touch the html portion mentioned previously, a reversal in css is required...

```
    .volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="100"] {
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="80"] {
    height: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="60"] {
    height: 35px;
    left: 40px;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="40"] {
    height: 40px;
    left: 60px;
}
.volume .volumeLevel[data-volume-level="20"] {
    height: 45px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoyjbM

Comment: That would not work, it would be wrong to go from high to low, instead of now from low to high. I think that is better for the user experience..

Comment: actually just tried your first input of rearranging them, since i am using position absolute, it seems to not matter how the elements look. And then the effect works.. Try my codepen...  did not think that would work heh, but it did ^^ i knew it would be simple somehow :D

Answer (score 0):

Change 'after' to 'before'

```
.volume{
  .volumeLevel:hover ~ .volumeLevel{
    background-color: #00A08C;
    &:before{
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
    }
  }
}
```

Check [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Irfan92/pen/rpLVpQ)

Comment: I changed to codepen to match the rearranging elements of Nikhils answer.. So this does not change anything im afraid...

Comment: check my codepen https://codepen.io/Irfan92/pen/rpLVpQ .   I just changed 'after' to 'before'

Comment: try rearranging the buttons... so its 20%, 40%, etc. instead of reverse.. It does not change the fact that this is not the answer... thanks anyway.